# How can I set a password if Linux Mint logs me in without a password?

Tags: linux-mint, password-protection

My install of Linux Mint Xfce boots up without asking for a password.
Where can I change this to require a password?

Comment: Do you have a password set for your user?

Comment: When you installed Mint, you specified a password (probably the same one used for root).  You can verify this by logging out of the session.  You should get a login screen asking for a password (and you can test your password).  If you originally specified something different and you're locked out, just reboot.  There is a different setting for whether you need a password to log in at startup.  Different implementations of Xfce give it different names, but go to the system settings and look for something like "Auto Login".  (cont'd)

Comment: That will let you change it so booting takes you to the login screen.  This is sometimes grouped under settings for User, Login, or Startup.